# Convert hex to binary

Tags: python, string, binary, hex, string-formatting

I have ABC123EFFF.

I want to have 001010101111000001001000111110111111111111 (i.e. binary repr. with, say, 42 digits and leading zeroes).

How?

Comment: *I have `ABC123EFFF`* -- `ABC123EFFF` is a string or number (i.e., `0xABC123EFFF`)?

Comment: If it is a string, this lambda I found online years ago might be helpful:

binary = lambda x: "".join(reversed( [i+j for i,j in zip( *[ ["{0:04b}".format(int(c,16)) for c in reversed("0"+x)][n::2] for n in [1,0] ] ) ] ))

binary("ABC123EFFF")

'1010101111000001001000111110111111111111'

Also works for leading zeros.

Answer (score 154):

For solving the left-side trailing zero problem:

---

```
my_hexdata = "1a"

scale = 16 ## equals to hexadecimal

num_of_bits = 8

bin(int(my_hexdata, scale))[2:].zfill(num_of_bits)
```

---

It will give 00011010 instead of the trimmed version.

Comment: Calculation for the number of bits is `len(my_hexdata) * log2(scale)`.

Comment: Doesn't provide leading zeros if hex string starts with 00.

Comment: @Dragon
myhex = '1A'
bin(int(myhex, 16))[2:].zfill(8)  >>> '00011010'
zhex = '00'
bin(int(zhex, 16))[2:].zfill(8)  >>> '00000000'
It appears that this works even when the hex string is '00'.

Comment: @DeanM This does not work when you have leading zeros. E.g., you get `01001000` instead of `0000000001001000` when you've `zhex='0048'`. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28913296/4177781) works for me.

Answer (score 85):

> ### Convert hex to binary
>
> I have ABC123EFFF.
>
> I want to have 001010101111000001001000111110111111111111 (i.e. binary
>   repr. with, say, 42 digits and leading zeroes).

### Short answer:

The new f-strings in Python 3.6 allow you to do this using very terse syntax:

```
>>> f'{0xABC123EFFF:0>42b}'
'001010101111000001001000111110111111111111'
```

or to break that up with the semantics:

```
>>> number, pad, rjust, size, kind = 0xABC123EFFF, '0', '>', 42, 'b'
>>> f'{number:{pad}{rjust}{size}{kind}}'
'001010101111000001001000111110111111111111'
```

### Long answer:

What you are actually saying is that you have a value in a hexadecimal representation, and you want to represent an equivalent value in binary.

The value of equivalence is an integer. But you may begin with a string, and to view in binary, you must end with a string.

### Convert hex to binary, 42 digits and leading zeros?

We have several direct ways to accomplish this goal, without hacks using slices.

First, before we can do any binary manipulation at all, convert to int (I presume this is in a string format, not as a literal):

```
>>> integer = int('ABC123EFFF', 16)
>>> integer
737679765503
```

alternatively we could use an integer literal as expressed in hexadecimal form:

```
>>> integer = 0xABC123EFFF
>>> integer
737679765503
```

Now we need to express our integer in a binary representation.

### Use the builtin function, `format`

Then pass to `format`:

```
>>> format(integer, '0>42b')
'001010101111000001001000111110111111111111'
```

This uses the formatting specification's [mini-language](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).

To break that down, here's the grammar form of it:

```
[[fill]align][sign][#][0][width][,][.precision][type]
```

To make that into a specification for our needs, we just exclude the things we don't need:

```
>>> spec = '{fill}{align}{width}{type}'.format(fill='0', align='>', width=42, type='b')
>>> spec
'0>42b'
```

and just pass that to format

```
>>> bin_representation = format(integer, spec)
>>> bin_representation
'001010101111000001001000111110111111111111'
>>> print(bin_representation)
001010101111000001001000111110111111111111
```

### String Formatting (Templating) with `str.format`

We can use that in a string using `str.format` method:

```
>>> 'here is the binary form: {0:{spec}}'.format(integer, spec=spec)
'here is the binary form: 001010101111000001001000111110111111111111'
```

Or just put the spec directly in the original string:

```
>>> 'here is the binary form: {0:0>42b}'.format(integer)
'here is the binary form: 001010101111000001001000111110111111111111'
```

### String Formatting with the new f-strings

Let's demonstrate the new f-strings. They use the same mini-language formatting rules:

```
>>> integer = 0xABC123EFFF
>>> length = 42
>>> f'{integer:0>{length}b}'
'001010101111000001001000111110111111111111'
```

Now let's put this functionality into a function to encourage reusability:

```
def bin_format(integer, length):
    return f'{integer:0>{length}b}'
```

And now:

```
>>> bin_format(0xABC123EFFF, 42)
'001010101111000001001000111110111111111111'
```

---

### Aside

If you actually just wanted to encode the data as a string of bytes in memory or on disk, you can use the `int.to_bytes` method, which is only available in Python 3:

```
>>> help(int.to_bytes)
to_bytes(...)
    int.to_bytes(length, byteorder, *, signed=False) -> bytes
...
```

And since 42 bits divided by 8 bits per byte equals 6 bytes:

```
>>> integer.to_bytes(6, 'big')
b'\x00\xab\xc1#\xef\xff'
```

Answer (score 76):

```
import binascii

binary_string = binascii.unhexlify(hex_string)
```

Read

[binascii.unhexlify](http://docs.python.org/library/binascii.html#binascii.unhexlify)

Return the binary data represented by the hexadecimal string specified as the parameter.

Comment: This returns "binary" as in the actual bytes, but it does not convert it to a printable representation as "0" and "1".

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/binascii.html is subtitled Convert between binary and ASCII. Doesn't that mean it returns a string?

Comment: Yes, it returns a string containing the bytes represented, e.g.
>>> unhexlify("ab")
"\xab"

Comment: Any idea how to return "001010100" ?

Comment: works only if hex_string has an even number of hexadecimal digits

Comment: I don't know why this was voted up as it doesn't answer the OP's actual request - see any of the other posts for an answer

Comment: This does not solve the OP's question.

Answer (score 61):

```
bin(int("abc123efff", 16))[2:]
```

Comment: If the input is "1a" this gives "11010", not "00011010" which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: It's quite reasonable to need the leading zeros (and to not need them). You might want the null byte 0x00 to be eight zero bits for example - this is important for some applications. Also the OP has a leading zero in his example (but I suspect that's just random in this case!)

Answer (score 33):

```
>>> bin( 0xABC123EFFF )
```

'0b1010101111000001001000111110111111111111'

Comment: Doesn't provide leading zeros if hex string starts with 00.

Answer (score 20):

Use Built-in [format() function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) and [int() function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int)
It's simple and easy to understand. It's little bit simplified version of [Aaron answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37221884/10228048)

**int()**

```
int(string, base)
```

**format()**

```
format(integer, # of bits)
```

**Example**

```py
# w/o 0b prefix
>> format(int("ABC123EFFF", 16), "040b")
1010101111000001001000111110111111111111

# with 0b prefix
>> format(int("ABC123EFFF", 16), "#042b")
0b1010101111000001001000111110111111111111

# w/o 0b prefix + 64bit
>> format(int("ABC123EFFF", 16), "064b")
0000000000000000000000001010101111000001001000111110111111111111
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16926130/convert-to-binary-and-keep-leading-zeros-in-python)

Answer (score 13):

```
"{0:020b}".format(int('ABC123EFFF', 16))
```

Comment: Doesn't provide leading zeros if hex string starts with 00.

Comment: The question says 42 digits, not 20?

Comment: @amsquareb Congrats on commenting on a 14 year old answer ;)

Comment: @Markus Is it said or written anywhere that you can comment only within some time period? I commented when I saw the answer - simple. And the reasons for your sarcasm is not obvious to me because I can't see why later comments would be any less valid or important than earlier comments.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a fairly raw way to do it using bit fiddling to generate the binary strings.

The key bit to understand is:

```
(n & (1 << i)) and 1
```

Which will generate either a 0 or 1 if the i'th bit of n is set.

```
import binascii

def byte_to_binary(n):
    return ''.join(str((n & (1 << i)) and 1) for i in reversed(range(8)))

def hex_to_binary(h):
    return ''.join(byte_to_binary(ord(b)) for b in binascii.unhexlify(h))

print hex_to_binary('abc123efff')

>>> 1010101111000001001000111110111111111111
```

Edit: using the "new" ternary operator this:

```
(n & (1 << i)) and 1
```

Would become:

```
1 if n & (1 << i) or 0
```

(Which TBH I'm not sure how readable that is)

Comment: I know this is old, but what exactly is the point of the "and 1"?

Comment: It's for the old days of python before the ternary operator.  The (n & (1 << i)) will either return zero or something other than zero.  We only want a one or zero, so that "and 1" is there to ensure that.

Comment: This script worked best for me to convert a crypto private key in hex to binary for testing purposes. Does anyone know how to split the binary string into 8 bit chunks and print it out? i.e. `01111001` `11111110`.

Answer (score 6):

This is a slight touch up to Glen Maynard's solution, which I think is the right way to do it.  It just adds the padding element.

```
    def hextobin(self, hexval):
        '''
        Takes a string representation of hex data with
        arbitrary length and converts to string representation
        of binary.  Includes padding 0s
        '''
        thelen = len(hexval)*4
        binval = bin(int(hexval, 16))[2:]
        while ((len(binval)) < thelen):
            binval = '0' + binval
        return binval
```

Pulled it out of a class.  Just take out `self,`  if you're working in a stand-alone script.

Answer (score 6):

I added the calculation for the number of bits to fill to Onedinkenedi's solution.  Here is the resulting function:

```
def hextobin(h):
  return bin(int(h, 16))[2:].zfill(len(h) * 4)
```

Where 16 is the base you're converting from (hexadecimal), and 4 is how many bits you need to represent each digit, or log base 2 of the scale.

Answer (score 3):

Replace each hex digit with the corresponding 4 binary digits:

```
1 - 0001
2 - 0010
...
a - 1010
b - 1011
...
f - 1111
```

Comment: Or replace each pair of hex digits with the corresponding 8 binary digits, or replace each triplet of hex digits with the corresponding 12 binary digits ... or replace each 10 hex digits, with the corresponding 40 binary digits - Oops! back where we started!

Answer (score 2):

hex --> decimal then decimal --> binary

```
#decimal to binary 
def d2b(n):
    bStr = ''
    if n < 0: raise ValueError, "must be a positive integer"
    if n == 0: return '0'
    while n > 0:
        bStr = str(n % 2) + bStr
        n = n >> 1    
    return bStr

#hex to binary
def h2b(hex):
    return d2b(int(hex,16))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
# Python Program - Convert Hexadecimal to Binary
hexdec = input("Enter Hexadecimal string: ")
print(hexdec," in Binary = ", end="")    # end is by default "\n" which prints a new line
for _hex in hexdec:
    dec = int(_hex, 16)    # 16 means base-16 wich is hexadecimal
    print(bin(dec)[2:].rjust(4,"0"), end="")    # the [2:] skips 0b, and the
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use the module [coden](https://pypi.org/project/coden/) <sup>(note: I am the author of the module)</sup>

You can convert haxedecimal to binary there.

1. Install using [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/)

```sh
pip install coden
```

2. Convert

```py
a_hexadecimal_number = "f1ff"
binary_output = coden.hex_to_bin(a_hexadecimal_number)
```

The converting Keywords are:

- **hex** for hexadeimal
- **bin** for binary
- **int** for decimal
- **_to_** - the converting keyword for the function

So you can also format:
e. hexadecimal_output = bin_to_hex(a_binary_number)

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
import math

def hextobinary(hex_string):
    s = int(hex_string, 16) 
    num_digits = int(math.ceil(math.log(s) / math.log(2)))
    digit_lst = ['0'] * num_digits
    idx = num_digits
    while s > 0:
        idx -= 1
        if s % 2 == 1: digit_lst[idx] = '1'
        s = s / 2
    return ''.join(digit_lst)

print hextobinary('abc123efff')
```

Comment: This fails if hex_string is set to 'f0'

Answer (score 1):

The binary version of ABC123EFFF is actually 1010101111000001001000111110111111111111

For almost all applications you want the binary version to have a length that is a multiple of 4 with leading padding of 0s.

To get this in Python:

```
def hex_to_binary( hex_code ):
  bin_code = bin( hex_code )[2:]
  padding = (4-len(bin_code)%4)%4
  return '0'*padding + bin_code
```

Example 1:

```
>>> hex_to_binary( 0xABC123EFFF )
'1010101111000001001000111110111111111111'
```

Example 2:

```
>>> hex_to_binary( 0x7123 )
'0111000100100011'
```

Note that this also works in Micropython :)

Comment: Nice. For hex strings instead of hex values:   bin_code = bin(int(hex_code, 0))[2:]

Comment: I think you mean `bin_code = bin(int(hex_code, 16))[2:]`

Comment: Yes that's right. To clarify my answer: base 0 works if the hex string is prefixed with "0x"

Answer (score 1):

```
HEX_TO_BINARY_CONVERSION_TABLE = {
                              '0': '0000',

                              '1': '0001',

                              '2': '0010',

                              '3': '0011',

                              '4': '0100',

                              '5': '0101',

                              '6': '0110',

                              '7': '0111',

                              '8': '1000',

                              '9': '1001',

                              'a': '1010',

                              'b': '1011',

                              'c': '1100',

                              'd': '1101',

                              'e': '1110',

                              'f': '1111'}

def hex_to_binary(hex_string):
    binary_string = ""
    for character in hex_string:
        binary_string += HEX_TO_BINARY_CONVERSION_TABLE[character]
    return binary_string
```

when I time `hex_to_binary("123ade")`

```
  %timeit hex_to_binary("123ade")
```

here is the result:

```
 316 ns ± 2.52 ns per loop
```

Alternatively, you could use "join" method:

```
def hex_to_binary_join(hex_string):
    hex_array=[]
    for character in hex_string:
        hex_array.append(HEX_TO_BINARY_CONVERSION_TABLE[character])
    return "".join(hex_array)
```

I timed this too:

```
    %timeit hex_to_binary_join("123ade")
       397 ns ± 4.64 ns per loop
```

Comment: Don't use string concatenation. `return "".join(HEX_TO_BINARY_CONVERSION_TABLE[c] for c in hex_string)`

Answer (score 0):

i have a short snipped hope that helps :-)

```
input = 'ABC123EFFF'
for index, value in enumerate(input):
    print(value)
    print(bin(int(value,16)+16)[3:])

string = ''.join([bin(int(x,16)+16)[3:] for y,x in enumerate(input)])
print(string)
```

first i use your input and enumerate it to get each symbol. then i convert it to binary and trim from 3th position to the end. The trick to get the 0 is to add the max value of the input -> in this case always 16 :-)

the short form ist the join method. Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

In python 3:

```
hex_string='ABC123EFFF'
hex_integer = int(hh, 16)
binary_string = bin(hex_integer)

# Remove the '0b' prefix from the binary string  
binary_string2 = binary_string[2:]

print(binary_string)# output:0b1010101111000001001000111110111111111111
print(binary_string2) # output: 1010101111000001001000111110111111111111
```

Answer (score -1):

```
a = raw_input('hex number\n')
length = len(a)
ab = bin(int(a, 16))[2:]
while len(ab)<(length * 4):
    ab = '0' + ab
print ab
```

Comment: Where's the description/explanation?

Answer (score -1):

```
import binascii
hexa_input = input('Enter hex String to convert to Binary: ')
pad_bits=len(hexa_input)*4
Integer_output=int(hexa_input,16)
Binary_output= bin(Integer_output)[2:]. zfill(pad_bits)
print(Binary_output)
"""zfill(x) i.e. x no of 0 s to be padded left - Integers will overwrite 0 s
starting from right side but remaining 0 s will display till quantity x
[y:] where y is no of output chars which need to destroy starting from left"""
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 def conversion():
    e=raw_input("enter hexadecimal no.:")
    e1=("a","b","c","d","e","f")
    e2=(10,11,12,13,14,15)
    e3=1
    e4=len(e)
    e5=()
    while e3<=e4:
        e5=e5+(e[e3-1],)
        e3=e3+1
    print e5
    e6=1
    e8=()
    while e6<=e4:
        e7=e5[e6-1]
        if e7=="A":
            e7=10
        if e7=="B":
            e7=11
        if e7=="C":
            e7=12
        if e7=="D":
            e7=13
        if e7=="E":
            e7=14
        if e7=="F":
            e7=15
        else:
            e7=int(e7)
        e8=e8+(e7,)
        e6=e6+1
    print e8

    e9=1
    e10=len(e8)
    e11=()
    while e9<=e10:
        e12=e8[e9-1]
        a1=e12
        a2=()
        a3=1 
        while a3<=1:
            a4=a1%2
            a2=a2+(a4,)
            a1=a1/2
            if a1<2:
                if a1==1:
                    a2=a2+(1,)
                if a1==0:
                    a2=a2+(0,)
                a3=a3+1
        a5=len(a2)
        a6=1
        a7=""
        a56=a5
        while a6<=a5:
            a7=a7+str(a2[a56-1])
            a6=a6+1
            a56=a56-1
        if a5<=3:
            if a5==1:
                a8="000"
                a7=a8+a7
            if a5==2:
                a8="00"
                a7=a8+a7
            if a5==3:
                a8="0"
                a7=a8+a7
        else:
            a7=a7
        print a7,
        e9=e9+1
```

Answer (score -7):

```
no=raw_input("Enter your number in hexa decimal :")
def convert(a):
    if a=="0":
        c="0000"
    elif a=="1":
        c="0001"
    elif a=="2":
        c="0010"
    elif a=="3":
        c="0011"
    elif a=="4":
        c="0100"
    elif a=="5":
        c="0101"
    elif a=="6":
        c="0110"
    elif a=="7":
        c="0111"
    elif a=="8":
        c="1000"
    elif a=="9":
        c="1001"
    elif a=="A":
        c="1010"
    elif a=="B":
        c="1011"
    elif a=="C":
        c="1100"
    elif a=="D":
        c="1101"
    elif a=="E":
        c="1110"
    elif a=="F":
        c="1111"
    else:
        c="invalid"
    return c

a=len(no)
b=0
l=""
while b<a:
    l=l+convert(no[b])
    b+=1
print l
```