# Convert to binary and keep leading zeros

Tags: python, binary, formatting, bitwise-operators

I'm trying to convert an integer to binary using the bin() function in Python. However, it always removes the leading zeros, which I actually need, such that the result is always 8-bit:

Example:

```
bin(1) -> 0b1

# What I would like:
bin(1) -> 0b00000001
```

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: See also: [Python int to binary?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/699866/562769), especially [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21732313/562769) with the n-bit representation. Not exactly the same, but I came to this question searching my answer...

Answer (score 350, accepted):

Use the [`format()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format):

```
>>> format(14, '#010b')
'0b00001110'
```

The `format()` function simply formats the input following the [Format Specification mini language](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language). The `#` makes the format include the `0b` prefix, and the `010` size formats the output to fit in 10 characters width, with `0` padding; 2 characters for the `0b` prefix, the other 8 for the binary digits.

This is the most compact and direct option.

If you are putting the result in a larger string, use an [formatted string literal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) (3.6+) or use [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) and put the second argument for the `format()` function after the colon of the placeholder `{:..}`:

```
>>> value = 14
>>> f'The produced output, in binary, is: {value:#010b}'
'The produced output, in binary, is: 0b00001110'
>>> 'The produced output, in binary, is: {:#010b}'.format(value)
'The produced output, in binary, is: 0b00001110'
```

As it happens, even for just formatting a single value (so without putting the result in a larger string), using a formatted string literal is faster than using `format()`:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit("f_(v, '#010b')", "v = 14; f_ = format")  # use a local for performance
0.40298633499332936
>>> timeit.timeit("f'{v:#010b}'", "v = 14")
0.2850222919951193
```

But I'd use that only if performance in a tight loop matters, as `format(...)` communicates the intent better.

If you did not want the `0b` prefix, simply drop the `#` and adjust the length of the field:

```
>>> format(14, '08b')
'00001110'
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, this formatting is really helpful to me. I have started learning bit manipulation and I was googling for bit formatting for numbers in Python. Found this. Thank you.

Comment: Works nice. Can get a bit bulky though.
`format(192,'08b')+'.'+format(0,'08b')+'.'+format(2,'08b')+'.'+format(33,'08b')`
`11000000.00000000.00000010.00100001`

Comment: @tjt263: That's why I explicitly state that *If you are putting the result in a larger string, use an formatted string literal (3.6+) or use `str.format()` and put the second argument for the format() function after the colon of the placeholder `{:..}`:*

Comment: @tjt263: e.g. use `f"{192:08b}.{0:08b}.{2:08b}.{33:08b}"`.

Comment: Very nice. I never would have known that's what you meant from explanation alone. But now I've seen your example, I'll probably never forget it. Cheers.

Comment: @MartijnPieters what if I want the number of bits variable?  For example you have used ```format(14, '08b')``` but instead of 8, I need variable x there.

Comment: @efe373: you can format the second argument, it's just a string. E.g. `format(14, f"0{x}b")`. Or combine it into a single format string, `f"{14:0{x}b}"`.

Answer (score 145):

```
>>> '{:08b}'.format(1)
'00000001'
```

See: [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

---

Note for Python 2.6 or older, you cannot omit the positional argument identifier before `:`, so use

```
>>> '{0:08b}'.format(1)
'00000001'
```

Comment: There is no need to use `str.format()` here when `format()` will do. You are missing the `0b` prefix.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, `str.format` is more flexible than `format()` because it will allow you to do multiple variables at once. I keep forgetting that the `format` function even exists. Admittedly it's perfectly adequate in this case.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Exactly, when you are only using `str.format()` with just one `{}` element, no other text, you are *not* using string templating, you are formatting *one value*. In that case just use `format()`. :-)

Comment: This does not work anymore:     print("TCP: Option: Data: {:08b}".format(option_data))
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to tuple.__format__

Answer (score 52):

I am using

```
bin(1)[2:].zfill(8)
```

will print

```
'00000001'
```

Answer (score 11):

When using Python `>= 3.6`, you can use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) with [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec):

```
>>> var = 23
>>> f"{var:#010b}"
'0b00010111'
```

Explanation:

- `var` the variable to format
- `:` everything after this is the format specifier
- `#` use the alternative form (adds the `0b` prefix)
- `0` pad with zeros
- `10` pad to a total length off 10 (this includes the 2 chars for `0b`)
- `b` use binary representation for the number

Comment: No, it is not the cleanest, *not unless you do more with the string than just a single placeholder*. Otherwise `format(var, "#010b")` communicates *intent* much better. It is, however, the fastest option. But you know that already, right, because I already cover *all of what you posted* in my answer.

Comment: I agree @MartijnPieters, `format` is cleaner if you don't need it as part of a longer string.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the string formatting mini language (Thanks to @Martijn Pieters for the suggestion) idea:

```
def binary(num, length=8):
    return format(num, '#0{}b'.format(length + 2))
```

Demo:

```
print(binary(1))
```

Output:

```
'0b00000001'
```

Comment: The same formatting language can be used to include the prefix for you. Use `#`. There is also `format()`, which saves you having to do a full string template.

Answer (score 9):

I like python f-string formatting for a little more complex things like using a parameter in format:

```
>>> x = 5
>>> n = 8
>>> print(f"{x:0{n}b}")
00000101
```

Here I print variable `x` with following formatting: I want it to be left-filled with `0` to have length = `n`,  in `b` (binary) format. See Format Specification Mini-Language from previous answers for more.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you just want a simple one liner:

```
binary = ''.join(['{0:08b}'.format(ord(x)) for x in input])
```

Python 3

Comment: Note that the `[  ]` shouldn't be needed - `join()` accepts a generator expression. `''.join('{0:08b}'.format(ord(x)) for x in input)`

Comment: @ChristophBurschka note that because `str.join()` needs to make two passes, a generator input is first converted to a list before joining. This takes a bit of a toll on performance and do it’s actually *better* here to pass in a list comprehension rather than a generator expression. It’s one if them exceptions to the rule.

Answer (score 0):

While many solutions have been posted here and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37377982/remove-the-0b-in-binary) the fastest way (if you don't need the '0b' part in front) is combining **f'{x:'b'}' with .zfill(n) for padding**.

**Even if you want the leading '0b'** you can add it by using the following code:

`'0b'+f'{i:b}'.zfill(n)`

And it is **still faster** and **more readable** than using the `f"{x:0{n}b}"` method

Find relevant benchmarking code and results [here](https://github.com/Skorpinakos/benchmark-01)

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like this

```
("{:0%db}"%length).format(num)
```

Comment: Please at least use code block for your code snippet. And if you really want it to be a good answer, then also add some comments on why this solution is solving OP question.

Comment: You don’t need to use a different string formatting style just to add a variable width. Just add another placeholder: `"{:0{l}b}".format(num, l=length)`

Answer (score -3):

You can use zfill:

```
print str(1).zfill(2) 
print str(10).zfill(2) 
print str(100).zfill(2)
```

prints:

```
01
10
100
```

I like this solution, as it helps not only when outputting the number, but when you need to assign it to a variable... 
e.g. - 
x = str(datetime.date.today().month).zfill(2) will return x as '02' for the month of feb.

Comment: problem with zfill is it treats the binary string like a string and adds the zeros before the binary 'b' indicator... eg

`bin(14)`   
gives
` '0b1110' `   
and  
`bin(14).zfill(8)`  
gives  
` '000b1110' `
not 
` '0b00001110' `
which is whats desired

Answer (score -3):

You can use `string.rjust` method:

```
string.rjust(length, fillchar)
```

`fillchar` is optional

and for your Question you can write like this

```
'0b'+ '1'.rjust(8,'0)
```

so it will be '0b00000001'

Comment: There is a syntax error. But more importantly, it doesn't answer the question at all, which is about converting an `int` to its textual binary representation; you don't even start with an `int`.