# How to keep leading zeros in binary integer (python)?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to calculate a checksum for a hex serial word string using XOR. To my (limited) knowledge this has to be performed using the bitwise operator ^. Also, the data has to be converted to binary integer form. Below is my rudimentary code - but the checksum it calculates is 1000831. It should be 01001110 or 47hex. I think the error may be due to missing the leading zeros. All the formatting I've tried to add the leading zeros turns the binary integers back into strings. I appreciate any suggestions.

```
    word = ('010900004f')

    #divide word into 5 separate bytes
    wd1 = word[0:2] 
    wd2 = word[2:4]
    wd3 = word[4:6]
    wd4 = word[6:8]
    wd5 = word[8:10]

    #this converts a hex string to a binary string
    wd1bs = bin(int(wd1, 16))[2:] 
    wd2bs = bin(int(wd2, 16))[2:]
    wd3bs = bin(int(wd3, 16))[2:]
    wd4bs = bin(int(wd4, 16))[2:]

    #this converts binary string to binary integer
    wd1i = int(wd1bs)
    wd2i = int(wd2bs)
    wd3i = int(wd3bs)
    wd4i = int(wd4bs)
    wd5i = int(wd5bs)

    #now that I have binary integers, I can use the XOR bitwise operator to cal cksum
    checksum = (wd1i ^ wd2i ^ wd3i ^ wd4i ^ wd5i)

    #I should get 47 hex as the checksum
    print (checksum, type(checksum))
```

Comment: I think this has been addressed before [see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16926130/python-convert-to-binary-and-keep-leading-zeros)

Comment: 0x47 != 0b1001110. Very few odd numbers end in `0` in their binary representation.

Comment: @PyNEwbie That is true, but here we are facing an XY-problem par excellence.

Comment: What is a "binary integer"?  Why are you interpreting digit strings in base 2 as if they were in base 10?  I think you're getting the numbers and their representations mixed up, which is why you're going on this binary detour.

Comment: Sorry for the typo - indeed I expect 01000111.

Comment: @DSM - a binary integer is an integer expressed in base 2. The native data arrives as a hex string. You can't use a boolean XOR to calculate this kind of checksum. Hyperboreus had to use the bitwise operator as well in his very refined solution.

Comment: @PYNEwbie - Thanks - I did read that question prior and I tried using them, but being new to Python, it didn't appear to answer my question as my understanding of the format spec has me believing it only achieves string outputs.

Comment: @user3284986 I always find it practical to distinguish between the "representation" of a number and its "value". `0x2a`, `0b101010` and `42` all have the same value. But the value 42 can be represented as `0x2a`, `0b101010` or `42`. An integer is not binary, or decimal, or hexadecimal, ternary, unary or gray-coded: an integer is an integer, i.e. an element of Z. Its representation can be binary, decimal, etc, pp.

Comment: @user3284986: an integer isn't binary; it's just a number.  In your line `wd1i = int(wd1bs)`, you interpret a binary *representation* of a number as if it were a decimal representation of a number: `int('10')` gives 10 (base-10), not 2, which isn't what you want.  And this mistake was entirely unnecessary, because `^` acting on two integers will give you the xor you're looking for without any of these detours.

Comment: Thanks for all the help and advice. I will refrain from using the term "binary integer". I'm obviously new to Python - so in python and programming in general, what do you call a number that is an integer whose value is being represented in binary format within your program?

Answer (score 5):

Why use all this conversions and the costly string functions?

(I will answer the X part of your [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), not the Y part.)

```
def checksum (s):
    v = int (s, 16)
    checksum = 0
    while v:
        checksum ^= v & 0xff
        v >>= 8
    return checksum

cs = checksum ('010900004f')
print (cs, bin (cs), hex (cs) )
```

Result is 0x47 as expected. Btw 0x47 is 0b1000111 and not as stated 0b1001110.

Comment: Thanks - that is eloquent. And it does solve the X part, rendering the Y part superfluous. Superfluous but mysterious . . .

Comment: @user3284986 Glad to help. Not that mysterious, just check out the link PyNewbie posted in his comment to your question.

Comment: @Victory I wouldn't call it a trick, but a standard approach.

Answer (score 1):

Just modify like this.

before:

```
wd1i = int(wd1bs)
wd2i = int(wd2bs)
wd3i = int(wd3bs)
wd4i = int(wd4bs)
wd5i = int(wd5bs)
```

after:

```
wd1i = int(wd1bs, 2)
wd2i = int(wd2bs, 2)
wd3i = int(wd3bs, 2)
wd4i = int(wd4bs, 2)
wd5i = int(wd5bs, 2)
```

**Why your code doesn't work?**

Because you are misunderstanding `int(wd1bs)` behavior.
See doc [here](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#int). So Python `int` function expect `wd1bs` is 10 base by default.
But you expect `int` function to treat its argument as 2 base.
So you need to write as `int(wd1bs, 2)`

---

Or you can also rewrite your entire code like this. So you don't need to use `bin` function in this case. And this code is basically same as @Hyperboreus answer. :)

```
w = int('010900004f', 16)
w1 = (0xff00000000 & w) >> 4*8
w2 = (0x00ff000000 & w) >> 3*8
w3 = (0x0000ff0000 & w) >> 2*8
w4 = (0x000000ff00 & w) >> 1*8
w5 = (0x00000000ff & w)

checksum = w1 ^ w2 ^ w3 ^ w4 ^ w5

print hex(checksum)
#'0x47'
```

And this is more shorter one.

```
import binascii
word = '010900004f'
print hex(reduce(lambda a, b: a ^ b, (ord(i) for i in binascii.unhexlify(word))))
#0x47
```

Comment: All your lines `wx = (0x....` can be written as `wX = (w >> Y*8) & 0xff`. Just shift first and mask after, then it is always `0xff`.

Comment: @Hyperboreus: Ah this is more smarter way thanks. My code is always very verbose... :)

Comment: @user3284986: I added explanation See what's wrong in your code.

Comment: @user2931409 - Many thanks to you. You are spot on about my incorrect assumption regarding the base 10 default. I don't mind verbosity if it aids readability  - which is what a python newbie like myself needs . . . . But eventually, we all want to type as little as possible :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
s = '010900004f'
b = int(s, 16)
print reduce(lambda x, y: x ^ y, ((b>> 8*i)&0xff for i in range(0, len(s)/2)), 0)
```

Comment: Will fail on python3, which I suspect OP to be using, as he uses `print` as a function.

Comment: @Hyperboreus: possibly, but it's tagged 2.7.

Comment: @DSM I could swear it wasn't tagged for any specific version when I wrote that comment. I must have been blind.