# Remove the 0b in binary

Tags: python, string, character

I am trying to convert a binary number I have to take out the 0b string out.

I understand how to get a bin number

```
x = 17

print(bin(17))

'0b10001'
```

but I want to take the `0b` in the string out and I am having some issues with doing this. This is going to be within a function returning a binary number without the `0b`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use slice operation to remove the first two characters.

```
In [1]: x = 17

In [2]: y = bin(x)[2:]

In [3]: y
Out[3]: '10001'
```

Answer (score 5):

use python string `slice` operation.

```
a = bin(17)
b = bin(17)[2:]
```

to format this to 8-bits use `zfill`.

```
c = b.zfill(8)
```

Answer (score 5):

It's easy just make this function:

```
def f(n):print('{:0b}'.format(n))
f(17)
>>> 10001
```

Answer (score 4):

```
format(17, 'b')
>>> '10001'
```

Use the `format()` builtin. It also works for hexadecimal, simply replace `'b'` with `'x'`.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format

Comment: hexadecimal is 'x', not 'h' -- for all specifiers, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language

Answer (score 2):

```
bin(n).replace("0b", "")
```

This one is using replace
Where `n` is the provided decimal

Answer (score 2):

with Python 3.6 you can use f-strings

```
print( f'{x:b}' )
'10001'
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know why nobody suggested using `lstrip`.

```
integer = 17
bit_string = bin(integer)
final = bit_string.lstrip('-0b') # minus to also handle negations
print(final) # prints 10001
```

Comment: beware, for 0 this returns an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

inhexa=(hexanum.get()) # gets the hexa value
dec = int(inhexa,16) #changes the base ensures conversion into base 16 to interger

```
 b=bin(dec)[2:]  #converts int/dec into binary and shows string except first two digits
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this page will answer to developers performing byte handling therefore **performance oriented** there should be a **benchmarked comparison** of above methods.

Assuming we do not require padding (a subject this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16926130/convert-to-binary-and-keep-leading-zeros) tackles) the aforementioned solutions (including the top answer from the other thread) yield these results (for 10 million random 21-bit integers) :
[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeqoH.png)

Benchmark can be find [here](https://github.com/Skorpinakos/benchmark-01).

So the **f'{x:'b'}'** **proves faster** with the **intuitive slicing** method as a **close second** (results were consistent between runs on a r5-3600 cpu and 16GB of 2133MHz 19CL system memory).

In the end the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65208010/11184186) from [Diego Roccia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2091926/diego-roccia) was the fastest and pretty elegant.

Padding with leading zeros and further options of said method can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16926357/11184186) but using the **f'{x:'b'}' with .zfill() for padding** is faster than the solutions given there (find actual tests in [here](https://github.com/Skorpinakos/benchmark-01)).

**So the answer is**:
`f'{x:'b'}'`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Well, the easiest way, for Python 3.9.0 and above is by using String removeprefix() function which removes the prefix and returns the rest of the string.

```
x = 17

y = bin(17)
>>>'0b10001'

y.removeprefix("0b")
>>> '10001'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
print (bin(int(input().strip()))[2:])
```

Pythonic way to solve. ;)

Comment: In what sense is this "pythonic"?