# How to rm -fr * reliably?

Tags: bash, rm, glob, dotfiles

```
rm -fr *
```

won't delete `.files`

On the other hand,

```
rm -fr * .*
```

will delete too much!

Is there a reliable way to recursively delete all contents of a directory in Bash?

One way I can think of is:

```
rm -fr $PWD
mkdir $PWD
cd $PWD
```

This has the side-effect of deleting `$PWD` temporarily.

Comment: `rm -rf dir` is good as long dir is not the current working directory.

Comment: For future reference, this would be a better fit for [unix.stackexchange.com](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16926130/25507).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest to use first:

```
shopt -s dotglob
```

> `dotglob`: If set, bash includes filenames beginning with a `.` in the results of pathname expansion

Answer (score 1):

```
rm -fr * .*
```

is relatively "safe". `rm` is forbidden by POSIX from acting on `.` and `..`.

```
rm -rf . ..
```

will be a no-op, though it will return 1. If you don't want the error return, you can do:

```
rm -rf .[!.]*
```

which is POSIX standardized, no bash extension required.

You can also use find:

```
find . -delete
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `find` with `-delete` and `-maxdepth`:

```
find . -name "*" -delete -maxdepth 2
```

So let's say you are in the directory `temp` which looks like this:

```
./temp
     |_____dir1
     |        |_____subdir1
    X|_file  X|_file      |_file
     |
    X|_____dir2
             X|_file
```

Looking at the tree the files and directories which have an **`X`** next to them would be deleted using the command above. `subdir1` is spared, since the maximum depth at which find will delete a file is set at 2 and there is a file residing within it. `find` will delete files starting with `.` — however, it doesn't work for symbolic links.

> ```
>  -delete
>          Delete found files and/or directories.  Always returns true.
>          This executes from the current working directory as find recurses
>          down the tree. It will not attempt to delete a filename with a
>          ``/'' character in its pathname relative to ``.'' for security
>          reasons. Depth-first traversal processing is implied by this
>          option. Following symlinks is incompatible with this option.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The usual wisdom for UNIX is to use something like:

```
rm -rf * .[!.]* ..?*
```

That will list all files that start with a dot or even double dot (without including the plain double dot (`./..`).

But that globbing expansion will keep the asterisk if files of that type do not exist.

Let's test:

```
$ mkdir temp5; cd temp5
$ touch {,.,..}{aa,bb,cc}
$ echo $(find .)
. ./aa ./cc ./..bb ./..aa ./.cc ./.bb ./..cc ./.aa ./bb
```

And, as indicated, this will include all files:

```
$ echo * .[!.]* ..?*
aa bb cc .aa .bb .cc ..aa ..bb ..cc
```

But if one of the types doesn't exist, the asterisk will stay:

```
$ rm ..?*
$ echo * .[!.]* ..?*
aa bb cc .aa .bb .cc ..?*
```

We need to avoid arguments that contain an asterisk to workaround this issue.