# Convert an Integer into 32bit Binary Python

Tags: python

I am trying to make a program that converts a given integer(limited by the value 32 bit int can hold) into 32 bit binary number. For example 1 should return (000..31times)1. I have been searching the documents and everything but haven't been able to find some concrete way. I got it working where number of bits are according to the number size but in String. Can anybody tell a more efficient way to go about this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python convert to binary and keep leading zeros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16926130/python-convert-to-binary-and-keep-leading-zeros)

Comment: Can you show us some code

Comment: Are you looking for 2's complement representation?

Comment: Yes, I want this representation because I am trying to build an webapp which mimics the Assembler(with limited functionality)

Answer (score 31):

`'{:032b}'.format(n)` where `n` is an integer. If the binary representation is greater than 32 digits it will expand as necessary:

```
>>> '{:032b}'.format(100)
'00000000000000000000000001100100'
>>> '{:032b}'.format(8589934591)
'111111111111111111111111111111111'
>>> '{:032b}'.format(8589934591 + 1)
'1000000000000000000000000000000000'    # N.B. this is 33 digits long
```

Comment: But this returns a string,I need a binary number because I want to add features like left shift and right shift also.

Comment: @PoojaGupta You are looking for an `int`

Comment: How about converting negative values?

Answer (score 7):

You can just left or right shift integer and convert it to string for display if you need.

```
>>> 1<<1
2
>>> "{:032b}".format(2)
'00000000000000000000000000000010'
>>>
```

or if you just need a binary you can consider bin

```
>>> bin(4)
'0b100'
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
x = 1234
print(f"{x:032b}")  # 00000000000000000000010011010010
```

Answer (score 0):

Say for example the number you want to convert into 32 bit binary is 4. So, num=4.
Here is the code that does this: "s" is the empty string initially.

```
for i in range(31,-1,-1):
    cur=(num>>i) & 1 #(right shift operation on num and i and bitwise AND with 1)
    s+=str(cur)
print(s)#s contains 32 bit binary representation of 4(00000000000000000000000000000100)

00000000000000000000000000000100
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say

```
a = 4
print(bin(a))  # 0b101
```

For the output you may append 0s from LSB to till 101 to get the 32bit address for the integer - 4.
If you don't want 0b you may slice it

```
print(bin(a)[-3:])  # 101
```