# Python byte array to bit array

Tags: python, type-conversion, bit-manipulation, byte, bit

I want to parse some data with Python and scapy.
Therefor I have to analyse single bits. But at the moment I have for example UDP packets with some payload like:

```
bytes = b'\x18\x00\x03\x61\xFF\xFF\x00\x05\x42\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF'
```

Is there any elegant way to convert the bytes so that I can access single bits like:

```
bytes_as_bits = convert(bytes)
bit_at_index_42 = bytes_as_bits[42]
```

Comment: So.. what will be bit `8` for example? An MSB of the second byte? An LSB of it?

Comment: Have you tried something like `''.join(f'{byte:b}' for byte in bytes)`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That will work:

```
def access_bit(data, num):
    base = int(num // 8)
    shift = int(num % 8)
    return (data[base] >> shift) & 0x1
```

If you'd like to create a binary array you can use it like this:

```
[access_bit(data,i) for i in range(len(data)*8)]
```

Answer (score 7):

If you would like to have the bits string, or to spare yourself from creating a function, I would use format() and ord(), let me take a simpler example to illustrate

```
bytes = '\xf0\x0f'
bytes_as_bits = ''.join(format(ord(byte), '08b') for byte in bytes)
```

This should output: '1111000000001111'

If you want LSB first you can just flip the output of format(), so:

```
bytes = '\xf0\x0f'
bytes_as_bits = ''.join(format(ord(byte), '08b')[::-1] for byte in bytes)
```

This should output: '0000111111110000'

Now you want to use `b'\xf0\x0f'` instead of `'\xf0\x0f'`. For python2 the code works the same, but for python3 you have to get rid of ord() so:

```
bytes = b'\xf0\x0f'
bytes_as_bits = ''.join(format(byte, '08b') for byte in bytes)
```

And flipping the string is the same issue.

I found the format() functionality [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16926130/convert-to-binary-and-keep-leading-zeros-in-python).
And the flipping ([::-1]) functionality [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python).

Comment: This and the accepted answer have advantages over one another.

Answer (score 4):

Hm, there is no builtin `bits` type in python, but you can do something like

```
>>> bin(int.from_bytes(b"hello world", byteorder="big")).lstrip('0b')
'110100001100101011011000110110001101111001000000111011101101111011100100110110001100100'
```

The `.lstrip('0b')` method will remove any leading `'0b'` characters in the output of the `bin()` function.

Comment: How does your answer handle large byte arrays?

Comment: Payload doesnt seem to be large in this particular case.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> n=17
>>> [(n & (1<<x))>>x for x in [7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0]]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

To extend @Liran's answer I have added `byteorder` as an input argument which defaults to 'big'.
*Note I am not refering to bit packing within the bytes*.

```
def access_bit(b: bytearray, n: int, byteorder: str = "big") -> int:
    """
    Returns the boolean value of the nth bit (n) from the byte array (b).
    The byteorder argument accepts the literal strings ['little', 'big'] and
    refers to the byte order endianness
    """
    base = int(n // 8)
    shift = int(n % 8)
    if byteorder == "big":
        return (b[-base - 1] >> shift) & 0x1
    elif byteorder == "little":
        return (b[base] >> shift) & 0x1
    else:
        raise KeyError("byteorder only recognises 'big' or 'little'")
```

`access_bit(b, 0)` returns the **least significant bit** of the **least significant byte** assuming **big-endian**

`access_bit(b, 7)` returns the **most significant bit** of the **least significant byte** assuming **big-endian**

`access_bit(b, 0, 'little')` returns the **least significant bit** of the **least significant byte** specifying **little-endian**

`access_bit(b, 7)` returns the **most significant bit** of the **least significant byte** assuming **little-endian**

Specifying an index `n` outside the range of the bytearray will result in an error (i.e. `access_bit(b'\x05\x01', 16)` results in an error as the max index of the bytearray is 15)

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a simple lambda expression to convert the bytes to a string:

```
>>> bytes = b'\x18\x00\x03\x61\xFF\xFF\x00\x05\x42\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF'
>>> convert = lambda x: f"{int.from_bytes(x, 'big'):b}"
>>> bytes_as_bits = convert(bytes)
>>> bytes_as_bits[42]
'1'
>>> _
```

`'big'` is the byteorder to be used. The [official python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes) describes it as follows:

> The byteorder argument determines the byte order used to represent the integer. If byteorder is "big", the most significant byte is at the beginning of the byte array. If byteorder is "little", the most significant byte is at the end of the byte array. To request the native byte order of the host system, use sys.byteorder as the byte order value.