Efficient bitarray operations in Python
I'm implementing a class for handling arrays of bit values in Python. So far, here is what I did:
class Bitarray:
    """ Representation of an array of bits.
    :param bits: the list of boolean values (i.e. {False, True}) of the bitarray.
    """
    def __init__(self, values:list[bool]):
        self._bits:list[bool] = values
        self._length:int = len(values)

    @staticmethod
    def from_bytes(data:bytes, byteorder:str = None):
        def _access_bit(data, index):
            """ Credits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43787831/23022499
            """
            base = int(index // 8)
            shift = int(index % 8)
            return (data[base] >> shift) & 0x1
        
        if byteorder == None:
            byteorder = sys.byteorder
        elif byteorder != 'little' and byteorder != 'big':
            raise ValueError('Param byteorder must be either "little" or "big".')
        
        bin_data = [_access_bit(data, i) for i in range(len(data) * 8)]
        bin_data = [bool(b) for b in bin_data]
        return Bitarray(bin_data) if byteorder == 'big' else Bitarray(bin_data[::-1])
    
    def __getitem__(self, index) -> bool:
        return self._bits[index]
    
    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return self._length
    
    # bit-wise operations
    def __and__(self, other):
        if type(other) != Bitarray:
            raise TypeError("Unsupported operand type(s) for &: '{}' and '{}'".format(type(self), type(other)))
        
        if self._length != len(other):
            raise IndexError("The arguments for bitwise operations must have same length.")
        
        return Bitarray([(a & b) for a, b in zip(self._bits, other._bits)])

    def __or__(self, other):
        if type(other) != Bitarray:
            raise TypeError("Unsupported operand type(s) for &: '{}' and '{}'".format(type(self), type(other)))
        
        if self._length != len(other):
            raise IndexError("The arguments for bitwise operations must have same length.")
        
        return Bitarray([(a | b) for a, b in zip(self._bits, other._bits)])

    def __xor__(self, other):
        if type(other) != Bitarray:
            raise TypeError("Unsupported operand type(s) for &: '{}' and '{}'".format(type(self).__name__, type(other).__name__))
        
        if self._length != len(other):
            raise IndexError("The arguments for bitwise operations must have same length.")
        
        return Bitarray([(a ^ b) for a, b in zip(self._bits, other._bits)])

    # to string
    def __str__(self):
        return ''.join(str(int(b)) for b in self._bits)

If you are wondering about the usage, I want to generate random values using os.urandom() and then perform bitwise operations with these values. An example:
import os
import sys

a = Bitarray.from_bytes(os.urandom(16 // 8), sys.byteorder)
b = Bitarray.from_bytes(os.urandom(16 // 8), sys.byteorder)

print('XOR result: {}'.format(a ^ b))

By far, what I've done works. But I am pretty sure this is so inefficient that for those who are reading this and know way more about Python, I just committed some horrible sin. :P
Jokes aside, iterating over boolean values for bitwise operations can't be good, right? Is there some more efficient way to do this?
P.S. For those who are curious, I am trying to build a cryptographic protocol which uses random keys and xor operations. I know about some modules like cryptography, bitarray and others but I thought it would be funnier to try to implement something on my own. Sorry for the lack of documentation and comments, I'll try to improve!
EDIT: Of course one may ask why do I need to use bit arrays if I could just perform bitwise operations using bytes. I need to access the single bit values and I would like my Bitarray class to be able to perform bitwise operations without having to move back to bytes everytime.

How long are your actual arrays? Surely more than 16 bits?

"I need to access the single bit values" - How often? And how often do you use which other operations?

@nocomment The size of the arrays can vary, let's suppose that for symmetric cryptography I'd like to use arrays of 256 bits. I am not planning of using asymmetric cryptography, but in that case I could need keys of much bigger size, let's say 2048 bits.
In this protocol I would say I need to perform around 54n XOR operations and 26n AND operations. Test are made on n: 50~300. I don't have real world data right now, but it should work for way bigger values of n. n is the size of a string so it's completely arbitrary, it could be "hello" or a genomic sequence.

first test code on some data to see if it is really inefficient

@furas I am going to, but I felt like mine was a very dirty solution and there was something better known to the experts.

I suggest using Python's infinite precision integers to hold the values since all the binary operations can be performed directly on them. Quick edit of your code:
import os
import sys

class Bitarray:
    def __init__(self, bits, value=0):
        if value >= (1 << bits):
            raise ValueError(f'value does not fit into {bits} bit(s)')
        self._bits: int = value
        self._length: int = bits

    @classmethod
    def from_bytes(cls, data: bytes, byteorder: str = None):
        if byteorder is None:
            byteorder = sys.byteorder
        elif byteorder != 'little' and byteorder != 'big':
            raise ValueError('Param byteorder must be either "little" or "big".')
        value = int.from_bytes(data, byteorder)
        return cls(len(data) * 8, value)

    def __getitem__(self, index) -> bool:
        return bool(self._bits & (1 << index))

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return self._length

    # bit-wise operations
    def __and__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Bitarray):
            raise TypeError("Unsupported operand type(s) for &: '{}' and '{}'".format(type(self), type(other)))
        if self._length != len(other):
            raise IndexError("The arguments for bitwise operations must have same length.")
        return Bitarray(self._length, self._bits & other._bits)

    def __or__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Bitarray):
            raise TypeError("Unsupported operand type(s) for &: '{}' and '{}'".format(type(self), type(other)))
        if self._length != len(other):
            raise IndexError("The arguments for bitwise operations must have same length.")
        return Bitarray(self._length, self._bits | other._bits)

    def __xor__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Bitarray):
            raise TypeError("Unsupported operand type(s) for &: '{}' and '{}'".format(type(self).__name__, type(other).__name__))
        if self._length != len(other):
            raise IndexError("The arguments for bitwise operations must have same length.")
        return Bitarray(self._length, self._bits ^ other._bits)

    # to string
    def __str__(self):
        return format(self._bits, f'0{self._length}b')

    def __repr__(self):
        length = (self._length + 3) // 4
        return f'Bitarray(bits={self._length}, value=0x{self._bits:0{length}X})'

a = Bitarray(8, 0xAF)
b = Bitarray(8, 0x55)
print(repr(a), repr(b))
print(a & b)
print(a | b)
print(a ^ b)
c = Bitarray.from_bytes(os.urandom(32))
print(repr(c))
d = Bitarray.from_bytes(b'\xff\x00')
print(repr(d))
e = Bitarray.from_bytes(b'\xff\x00', 'big')
print(repr(e))

Output:
Bitarray(bits=8, value=0xAF) Bitarray(bits=8, value=0x55)
00000101
11111111
11111010
Bitarray(bits=256, value=0x976E921A9C93C7D5D9C4BB6722B38064A04EA882CA4DF76981F52C7097E0DDFF)
Bitarray(bits=16, value=0x00FF)
Bitarray(bits=16, value=0xFF00)


Thanks for the answer! I'll definitely try it and see the difference :)
