# How to multiply correctly in my situation

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-3.6

```
def polmul(n1,n2):
      n1 = int (n1, 2)
      s = int ('0', 2)
      for c in n2 [:: -1]:
            if (c == '1'):
                 s = s ^ n1
            n1*=2
      Bin_out = bin(s)[2:].zfill(2)
      Mul = str(Bin_out)
      return Mul
n1 = '0000011'
n2 = '100010111'
x = polmul(n1,n2)
```

(result is 1100111001)

It is skipping zeros at the beginning.
I need result 000001100111001
Please help

Comment: What does your function do?

Comment: are you multiplying polynomials in GF(2)? would be nice if you mentioned that...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert to binary and keep leading zeros in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16926130/convert-to-binary-and-keep-leading-zeros-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Bin_out = bin(s)[2:].zfill(15)
```

will do the trick, since `*.zfill(fill_width)` pads string on the left with zeros to `fill_width` (`fill_width=15` in your case)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.