# Unknown format code 'b' for object of type 'str'

Tags: python, format

```
def reverseBits(self, n):
    binary = '{0:08b}'.format(n)
    rev = reversed(binary)
    print(rev)
    return rev
```

I get the error:

ValueError: Unknown format code 'b' for object of type 'str'

It says that this error occurs on line 20 even though there is no line 20.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The problem is, you are trying to format a `string` as binary which is not possible this way. This approach can only be used to format `integers` as binary. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18815820/convert-string-to-binary-in-python) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16926130/convert-to-binary-and-keep-leading-zeros-in-python?rq=1)

Comment: please post your entire code

Comment: If you want us to debug this, we need to see the entire exception traceback, not just part of the first line, and we need to see a [mcve], not just a fragment of code that doesn't contain the part that's probably in error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are trying to convert a string to binary. First it must be converted to Int. What I mean is, say you are trying to get the reverse bits of the number `16`. In Base 2,  16 is `10000` and Reverse that is `00001`. The parameter you pass to the `.format` **Must** be of type int. 
Dont do `(...).format("16")` instead do `(...).format(16)`