# python integer to binary

Tags: python-3.x, binary

I am converting two integers to binary. Based on the maximum length of the two conversions, I want to fill `0`s for the short conversion so that the two conversions will have the same length. I am thinking I can pass the `m = max(length)` as a variable to reformat a `'{0:mb}'.format(x)`. But this does not work.

Is there a way I can do this or another way to work this? Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert to binary and keep leading zeros in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16926130/convert-to-binary-and-keep-leading-zeros-in-python)

Comment: `format(your_number, '#0%db' % your_desired_length)`