# Fix a method to convert list of integers to NumPy matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I want to create random integers and convert them in binary format via NumPy matrix. I wrote the following code:

```
def toBinary(C):
    l = []
    for x in C:
        b = [int(i) for i in bin(x)[2:]]
        l = np.vstack((l, np.array(b)))
    return l

list_vectors = [random.randint(0, 2 ** 64) for _ in range(2)]
print(toBinary(list_vectors))
```

But I still don't know how to solve this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 31, in <module>
    print(toBinary(list_vectors))
  File "test.py", line 27, in toBinary
    l = np.vstack((l, np.array(b)))
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/shape_base.py", line 234, in vstack
    return _nx.concatenate([atleast_2d(_m) for _m in tup], 0)
ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly
```

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: What does `print(np.array(b).shape)` give you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that the conversion to binary does not always return a binary number of same length.
If the first integer in C is, let's say 3, it'll give '0b11'. Stack this in the array, then try to convert 17. Oops, you're trying to concatenate '11' and '1001' together, it won't work.

What I did here then, is forcing the converted binary number length to 10 using the format() function ([Convert to binary and keep leading zeros in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16926130/convert-to-binary-and-keep-leading-zeros-in-python)).

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as random

def toBinary(C):
    binaries_length = 10
    bin_format = f'#0{binaries_length+2}b'
    array_rows = len(C)
    l = np.empty((array_rows, binaries_length))
    for i, x in enumerate(C):
        l[i,:] = np.array([int(i) for i in format(x, bin_format)[2:]])
    return l

list_vectors = [random.randint(0, 2 * 64) for _ in range(10)]

print(toBinary(list_vectors))
```

Also, the returned array is pre-allocated, since you now perfectly know what size it will be :

```
binaries_length = 10
bin_format = f'#0{10+2}b'
array_rows = len(C)
l = np.empty((array_rows, binaries_length))
```

By the way, the call random.randint(0, 2 ** 64) also triggers an exception because 2 ** 64 is insanely too high so I changed it to 2*64 here.

To go further, you can find the optimal binary length by finding the maximum of C.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will return a list instead of array, so make the necessary adjustments if you like:

```
def toBinary(C):
    l = []
    for x in C:
        b = [i for i in bin(x)[2:]]
        a="".join(b)
        a=int(a)
        l.append(a)
return l
```