# How to get range of bits from byte in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Want to extract bits from a binary or integer value. 
From one end i am sending `hex` value of `01 00 00` in a byte array.After receiving in other end, converting into integer then try to get range of bits from that. `hex(100000) = 65536`. Now i want range of bits from this value.

```
input_2 = 65536
result= bin(input_2)
```

The problem here is , its 3 byte(24bits) data so it should able give 19-24 bits value.

```
0001 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

so i want bit range from 19-24. How can i do?

Comment: can you explain what you are doing with an example

Comment: if you want 19-24 bits why are you using `-24:-19` negative index doesn't work that way -19 doesn't give 19th bit

Comment: Note that the value in your last example line is 1048576, not 65536. It's unclear if that is meant to be that way.

Comment: Modified the explanation please have a look guys.

Comment: I think this will give you the answer: ```format(65536,'#024b')
'0b0000010000000000000000'``` I will not post this as answer since this solution was given by @Martijn in the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16926130/convert-to-binary-and-keep-leading-zeros-in-python which @Qiu has commented to be a duplicate.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? Apparently the endianness of the sender and receiver differ. Extracting the 19th to 24th (inclusive) bits is done using bitwise operators, like `(x & 0xfc_00_00) >> 18`

Comment: @JenilDave anyway i got idea to deal with thanks.