# Representing a number using two bytes

Tags: python, python-2.7

What is the easiest way in Python to represent a number from `0` to `65535` using two bytes?

For example `300` in decimal is `0000000100101100` in binary and `012C` in hexadecimal.

What I want to get as output when I get `300` is two bytes:

- first is `00101100` (in binary representation)
- second is `00000001` (in binary representation)

What is the easiest way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure there is something better than this, though:

```
from struct import pack, unpack
unpack('BB', pack('H',300))
# gives (44, 1), the two bytes you were asking for
```

See [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment) to see what the available letter codes are, also be mindful of byte order.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the  low bits using `& 255` (i.e. bitwise AND with `0b11111111`):

```
>>> "{:08b}".format(300 & 255)
'00101100'
```

and the high bits by adding a bitwise shift:

```
>>> "{:08b}".format((300 >> 8) & 255)
'00000001'
```

For more information on the bitwise operators, see e.g. [the Python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators).

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for `struct.pack`:

```
>>> import struct
>>> i = 300
>>> struct.pack("H",i)
',\x01'
```

where the `,` is its ascii value - 44.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4859937), you could do the following :

```
>>> my_hexdata = hex(300)                                     
>>> scale = 16 ## equals to hexadecimal                       
>>> num_of_bits = 16                                          
>>> mybin = bin(int(my_hexdata, scale))[2:].zfill(num_of_bits)
>>> mybin                                                     
'0000000100101100'                                            
>>> mybin[:8]                                                 
'00000001'                                                    
>>> mybin[8:16]                                               
'00101100'
```

Comment: This is just `mybin = bin(300)[2:].zfill(16)`! Given that you *already have an integer*, why bother converting to hex and back?

Comment: You're right. I thought it was what asked the question.