# Handling of byte data after converting it to bits in Python

Tags: python, iot, sensors, payload

Could somebody help me with converting `7 byte` of data into binary value in Python?

The server receives a `7 byte` data using `MQTT` and I want to convert this data into binary, break it down and extract specific lengths of bits from this data in Python for further handling.

If I received:

```
810be320cab3d
```

I want to convert it to:

```
1000000100001011111000110010000011001010101100111101
```

store this in a variable, then later break this value down into a couple of piece so I can slice the value using `str()` or `truncate()`, I hope.

Comment: You've asked too many questions in a single unformatted question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425493/convert-hex-to-binary

Comment: Sorry for not formatting the question. My only question is whether it is possible/how to convert a 7 byte data into binary in Python.

Comment: Shouldn't that give you `1000000100001011111000110010000011001010101100111101`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple way:

```
data = '810be320cab3d'

bits = { '0':'0000', '1':'0001', '2':'0010', '3':'0011'
         '4':'0100', '5':'0101', '6':'0110', '7':'0111',
         '8':'1000', '9':'1001', 'a':'1010', 'b':'1011',
         'c':'1100', 'd':'1101', 'e':'1110', 'f':'1111' }

def main():
    r = ""
    for c in data:
        r += bits[c]
    print r

main()
```

Output:

```
1000000100001011111000110010000011001010101100111101
```

Comment: Ha!  @user5173426, yours is a cooler solution.  Mine's more readable though.  That second version is particularly trippy.

Answer (score 0):

```
hex2bin_map = {
   "0":"0000",
   "1":"0001",
   "2":"0010",
   "3":"0011",
   "4":"0100",
   "5":"0101",
   "6":"0110",
   "7":"0111",
   "8":"1000",
   "9":"1001",
   "A":"1010",
   "B":"1011",
   "C":"1100",
   "D":"1101",
   "E":"1110",
   "F":"1111",
}

print('0b{:016_b}'.format(int('810be320cab3d', 16)))
```

Shorter version:

```
print(bin(int('810be320cab3d', 16))[2:])
```

OUTPUT:

```
1000000100001011111000110010000011001010101100111101
```