# Initialization Vector displaying (Binary) using CBC in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, initialization-vector

Hey is there a way to Print the (binary) version of the IV and not the Hexadecimal?  I'm required to show it for class. I'm doing an encryption/decryption of plaintext using CBC mode and I have to show the IV in Binary and not hexadecimal.  I'm using Python 3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert hex to binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425493/convert-hex-to-binary)

Answer (score 0):

if you can convert the roman numeral to an integer than just use `bin(4)`