# Python - Converting raw hex to type 'int'

Tags: python, string, int, hex

I have raw hex from a com port that I want to represent as a hex value that I can use later for bitwise operations.

For example, I have 1035 and I want it as 0x1035.

I am relatively certain the hex() function is not what I want. This converts int(1035) into hex 40B.

I have tried concatenating a '0x' to my value, the problem I found with this is it is then type str, which I can't do bitwise &,|, etc. Converting it to int results in:
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0x1035'

I have tried converting the hex to binary, with the same problem as before with type str and not type int.

Life becomes way easier when I define, hex = 0x1035, for example. But I want this to be reusable for many messages from the com port.

How do I convert a string '0x1035' to a hex int? Or, how do I tell the interpreter that the int I have, 1035, I want interpreted as hex, 0x1035?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert hex to binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425493/convert-hex-to-binary)

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Comment: I understand your question as I needed the same thing. If you have a hex in str type, convert it to int. Python will handle it like hex in int type: i.e. int(hex_value_str, 16). Then, you can also do bit operations with this outcome as you do with hex int type.

Answer (score 0):

Some good comments above that point to good references.  2 things worth mentioning.  When you say you "have raw hex from a port" I'm assuming that when you ingest these numbers into python that the data type is a `string` that represents a hexadecimal value.  If that is the case, you can just convert it

```
In [17]: input_data = ['10', '1035', 'FF', 'A']                                 

In [18]: hex_data = [int(t, 16) for t in input_data]                            

In [19]: hex_data                                                               
Out[19]: [16, 4149, 255, 10]
```

Now that python is storing these things as integer values, you can do bitwise operations on them, which is executed in the base-2 representation, obviously.  Then you can express the output however you like.  Same underlying number is in memory...python can express it in many bases.

```
In [20]: d1 = 'A'                                                               

In [21]: d2 = '3'                                                               

In [22]: d1 = int(d1, 16)                                                       

In [23]: d2 = int(d2, 16)                                                       

In [24]: d1                                                                     
Out[24]: 10

In [25]: d2                                                                     
Out[25]: 3

In [26]: d1&d2                                                                  
Out[26]: 2

In [27]: # let's check...                                                       

In [28]: bin(d1)                                                                
Out[28]: '0b1010'

In [29]: bin(d2)                                                                
Out[29]: '0b11'

In [30]: # looks right.....  (it is)
```