# Convert values inside bracket into binary forms by using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex

there's a sample input file as follows(input1.txt)

(For your information, `4'hF` means its value is 15 by decimal and it is binary 4 bits and its value is `1111` as binary per each bit.
So, `4'hF` is same as `4'b1111`)

```
{pDHY_es[3:0]}                    = 4'hF;
{pDHY_asq,1'b0,pDHY_qr,1'b1}      = 4'hB;
{pQHY_yd,pRTY_a[2:0]}             = 4'h5;
{1'b0,1'b0,pDSY_qr,pDNR_pf}       = 4'h3;
{pQHT_yd[1:0],pDRY_pf,pTUCF_xlck} = 4'h9;
```

and What I want to do is to convert all the elements inside bracket(that starts with the letter'p') into its bit-assigned value. So In this case, the output would be as follows(output.txt)

```
pDHY_es[3:0] = 4'b1111;
pDHY_asq     = 1'b1;
pDHY_qr      = 1'b1;
pQHT_yd      = 1'b0;
pRTY_a[2:0]  = 3'b101;
pDSY_qr      = 1'b1;
pDNR_pf      = 1'b1;
pQHY_yd[1:0] = 2'b10;
pDRY_pf      = 1'b0;
pTUCF_xlck   = 1'b1;
```

To sum up, What I want to do is

1.extract all the element inside bracket that starts with the letter'p'.

2.put the value of each element into its bit-assigned form.

I've thought about using hex to binary converting function as follows:
[Convert hex to binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425493/convert-hex-to-binary)
but Itself doesn't seem to meet what I need:

Comment: Converting the hex to binary is easy.  Separating the group of signals to individual lines is quite difficult, because you'd need to know how many bits each signal was defined as.

Comment: @TimRoberts That's what I am talking about..

Comment: Unless you're doing thousands and thousands of lines, it's simply not worth the trouble to write a Verilog parser to extract the information you need.  I'm not sure why you would want to, anyway.

Comment: @TimRoberts Sadly, It does need hundreds to thousands of lines cases.. So that's why I use python to make it generated automatically

Comment: what is the difference of `1'b0` and `1'b1`

Comment: @rioV8 1'b0 means zero of 1bit, 1'b1 means one of 1bit

Comment: what is the semantics of these 2 items, are they hardcoded placeholders

Comment: @rioV8 They are not.. FYI, 2'b00,1'b0 means 2 digits , 1digit each and all meaning zero in decimal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse the lines with `split()` and `strip()`

```py
inp = """{pDHY_es[3:0]}                    = 4'hF;
{pDHY_asq,1'b0,pDHY_qr,1'b1}      = 4'hB;
{pQHY_yd,pRTY_a[2:0]}             = 4'h5;
{1'b0,1'b0,pDSY_qr,pDNR_pf}       = 4'h3;
{pQHT_yd[1:0],pDRY_pf,pTUCF_xlck} = 4'h9;"""

def convertBitpattern(s: str):
  numBits, bits = s.split("'")
  numBits = int(numBits)
  return numBits, format(int(bits[1:], 16 if bits[0] == 'h' else 2), f"0{numBits}b")

def getNumbits(field):
  numBits = 1
  isField = False
  if field[0] in '0123456789':
    numBits, _ = convertBitpattern(field)
  else:
    isField = True
    parts = field.split('[')
    if len(parts) == 2:
      numBits = int(parts[1].split(':')[0])+1
  return isField, numBits

for line in inp.split('\n'):
  fields, bitpattern = list(map(lambda x: x.strip().strip('{};'), line.split('=')))
  _, bits = convertBitpattern(bitpattern)
  for field in fields.split(','):
    isField, numBits = getNumbits(field)
    fieldBits, bits = bits[:numBits], bits[numBits:]
    if isField:
      print(f"{field:15} = {numBits}'b{fieldBits};")
```

Output

```
pDHY_es[3:0]    = 4'b1111;
pDHY_asq        = 1'b1;
pDHY_qr         = 1'b1;
pQHY_yd         = 1'b0;
pRTY_a[2:0]     = 3'b101;
pDSY_qr         = 1'b1;
pDNR_pf         = 1'b1;
pQHT_yd[1:0]    = 2'b10;
pDRY_pf         = 1'b0;
pTUCF_xlck      = 1'b1;
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer ! Can u please put comments to the codes?

Comment: @kts why?, can't you read python or is this a homework assignment and you need to comment your submission. If code is written well it does not need comments

Comment: I would not ask in detail like this if this is homework.. its funny to ask so. Never mind. if it is burden to u.

Comment: This code assumes that all names without bit fields are exactly 1 bit wide.  Maybe that's true for your design, but that's not true for Verilog in general.  And his question was not funny at all.  This is not a free consulting service.  We're here to help you on your way to a solution, not to deliver pre-canned solutions.

Comment: @TimRoberts What is not specked in the question I can only guess based on the example given

Comment: Yes, I get it.  I was not actually critiquing your answer, which solves 99% of the problem.  I just wanted to warn the OP about potential pitfalls.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom method named **hex_to_binary** and use **regex**

```
import re


def hex_to_binary(hex_value, num_bits):
    binary_value = bin(int(hex_value, 16))[2:]
    return f"{binary_value:0>{num_bits}}"


with open('input1.txt', 'r') as input_file, open('output.txt', 'w') as output_file:
    for line in input_file:
        matches = re.findall(r'{p([A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_0-9]*)\[(\d+:\d+)\]}\s*=\s*4\'h([0-9A-Fa-f]+);', line)

        for match in matches:
            variable_name = match[0]
            bit_range = match[1]
            hex_value = match[2]
            num_bits = int(bit_range.split(':')[0]) - int(bit_range.split(':')[1]) + 1
            binary_value = hex_to_binary(hex_value, num_bits)
            output_file.write(f"{variable_name}{bit_range} = {num_bits}'b{binary_value};\n")
```

Comment: I've tried this with same input and code, but it only returns ' DHY_es3:0 = 4'b1111; '